# MethodNotAllowedException when i click button to redirect to another view

Tags: php, laravel

Im currently creating a blog in Laravel to learn PHP/Laravel. The problem is that im getting:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

I have a table where i show all the posts with buttons "View" and "Edit" for each post. They redirect to the relevant view with the `id` and they work fine. When i open any post to view there is a button for edit aswell and this is where i get the error when i click it and i dont know why.

**show.blade.php** // this is the "View" for the post

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>

        <p class="lead">{{ $post->body }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Created at:</dt>
                <dd>{{ date('d M, y H:i', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Last Updated:</dt>
                <dd>{{ date('d M, y H:i', strtotime($post->updated_at)) }}</dd>
            </dl>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
                    </form>
                </div>﻿
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.update', $post->id) }}">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="title" name="title" rows="1"
                          style="resize:none;">{{ $post->title }}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">Body:</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="body" name="body"
                          rows="5">{{ $post->body }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Created at:</dt>
                    <dd>{{ date('M j, Y h:i:sa', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Last updated:</dt>
                    <dd>{{ date('M j, Y h:i:sa', strtotime($post->updated_at)) }}</dd>
                </dl>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Back</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**PostController.php** // this is the controller if you need it aswell

```
class PostController extends Controller {

public function index()
{
    //
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('posts/index')->withPosts($posts);
}

public function create()
{
    // return create new post form
    return view("posts/create");
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate data
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required'
    ));

    // store data in db
    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;

    $post->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved!');

    // redirect if succesfull
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}

public function show($id)
{
    //
    $post = Post::find($id);

    // redirect to view
    return view('posts/show')->with('post', $post);

}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('posts/edit')->with('post', $post);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

Comment: And your routes?

Comment: Can you provide your routes? Probably you are using wrong method in your routes (get instead of post).

Comment: `Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');

Route::get('about', 'PagesController@getAbout');

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using a form which have defined the method as `POST` but the route is defined as `GET`:

Change it to:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
</form>
```

Also, you could use a link instead of a form:

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Yeah.. im so blind. Thanks.